# The reason of different regression results between "enter" and "stepwise" methods

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, spss, stepwise-regression

I and one of my colleagues conducted regression analysis in SPSS. There is a significant difference in our regression results obtained using the "enter" and "stepwise" methods. All other settings of the two regression analyses are the same, except for the methods. There are five regressors and 19 cases.

With the "enter" method, the model is not significant (R2=.44, adjusted R2=0.16, p>0.2). But the predictor (regressor) of interest shows a significant effect on the dependent variable (p<0.05).

On the other hand, with the "stepwise" method, the model is significant (R2=.40, adjusted R2=0.36, p<0.01), and the predictor of interest also has a significant effect (p<0.01).

I would like to know why there is such a substantial difference between the two methods. Additionally, if we must use the "enter" method for regression, are there any ways to make the overall model look significant?

Comment: How many covariates are in the model with "enter"?

Comment: There are no covariates, only five regressors in both "enter" or "stepwise" regression.

Comment: Your edit includes a formula, and you are now trying to verify the adjusted R2. This is a different question. Briefly, your "regressors" likely include categorical variables. If a categorical variable has 10 levels, it is encoded as (and counts as) 9 separate "contrasts" or variables. So think carefully about your $k$.

Comment: Sorry, it is my fault.  All variables are not categorical variables. But the constant regressor was not included. So there are six regressors, including constant. And the adjusted R2 is different if k is six.

Comment: The large difference between $R^2$ and adjusted $R^2$ indicates you have extremely few observations -- far fewer than will support estimates for five regressors.  With your 18 cases, you can *hope,* optimistically, to fit a model with at most *two* regressors.

Comment: @whuber Thank you very much! Do you know the tools or formulas for calculating minimum sample size for regression analysis? Besides, could we use some algorithm to increase the sample size, like bootstrap?

Comment: (1) The bootstrap does not increase the sample size.  (2) No statistical procedure alone can increase the sample size: you can't create data with mathematics.  (3) There are various rules of thumb for ordinary least squares regression, but the most optimistic say you need an average of at least 10 observations for each coefficient you are estimating.

Comment: Thanks! But bootstrap can solve the problem of decreased adjusted R2 in my regression analysis, right?

Comment: I doubt that.  The bootstrap is not magical and typically it doesn't work well, or even at all, with such tiny datasets.

Answer (score 4):

For the uninitiated, the "enter" method is language endemic to SPSS. SPSS offers stepwise as a highly suggestive "tickbox" option in any regression setting. In all other software, the "enter method" is simply regression and stepwise requires several, deliberate additional steps. The truth is that most SPSS users consider or even use stepwise regression simply because it's there. It's a major design flaw in SPSS.

In this case, you refer to the "significance" of a model. However, if stepwise regression is performed, there is no well-defined concept of a "model" - the specific hypothesis which generates a $p$-value for overall model fit sets the coefficients for all covariates in a model to 0. But when the number of covariates entered into (or removed from) said model, the alternative hypothesis has been constrained by the stepwise procedure. The final stepwise model is optimized according to that algorithm to give the best $R^2$ and the best $p-value$ for overall fit without any account whatsoever for multiple testing. In short, the $p$ from the stepwise model doesn't tell you anything useful about the global model fit.

It is surprising that the "enter" method as you call it has not achieved global model fit. The increased $R^2$ but decreased adjusted $R^2$ seems to suggest you have too many variables in the model. When there are potentially too many variables to adjust properly in a model (or in any other case as well), a trained statistician would have performed a sample size calculation via simulation or other tools to determine the optimal balance of predictiveness (via inclusion of variables) and parsimony/reduced variance inflation (via exclusion of variables).

One example when a stepwise model selection *might* be performed regards adjustment for precision/blocking variables in a multiple regression model. Distinct from confounding adjustment, which must satisfy causal criteria *and* provide bidirectional prediction (stratification more precisely) between an exposure and an outcome, precision variables are causally unrelated to the exposure, but predict/stratify the response. In this case, some of the common predictive techniques can be applied, stepwise regression included, to identify the functional form of the prediction of conditional response. However, these details are not available at present.

However, I think all SPSS users should avoid stepwise regression because it is poorly regarded in the community and introduces issues of lack of generalization. Since you have already analyzed the data, I advocate to simply report the "enter" method provided you are certain all the adjustments are valid and relevant to the science.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply! Yes, the adjusted R2 is very low. But I think the number of independent variables is not the reason. Because there are only five regressors in the model.

Comment: Besides, you mentioned that results obtained through the 'enter' method can be reported directly. But if the overall model is not significant, does it still make sense for a particular independent variable to have a significant prediction on the dependent variable? The significant predictions of the regressors of interest perfectly align with our theoretical assumptions, which is crucial for us.

Comment: @AuroraChoi the "test" of "model fit" is dubious, particularly because it is not a hypothesis of interest. You can test the hypothesis as to whether a particular $\beta=0$ regardless of the overall model fit (or any hypothesis test thereof) *provided* the specific hypothesis, including the regressors *are prespecified*.

Comment: None of the SPSS procedures represent good statistical practice.